# How do I convert a flat JSON key to a dictionary path?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
temp = {"a": {"b": {"c": 123} } }
```

And I have the following flat JSON key and new value:

```
flat = "a.b.c"
new_val = 456
```

I'd like to change the nested dict value with the new one.
How do I transform the `"a.b.c"` to `temp["a"]["b"]["c"]`?

Note that I don't know the amount of layers in the JSON key, it can be `"a.b.c.d.f"` and it could be just `"a"`.

Comment: Split the key by "." then traverse the dict with each of the parts you get from that

Comment: But how do I traverse the dict? I don't know how many keys there are

Comment: Use a loop to go through the keys after splitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate the different keys (execpt the last one) to reach the final dict, then update the value

```
def update_dict_dot(values, key: str, val):
    keys = key.split(".")
    x = values
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        x = x[key]
    x[keys[-1]] = val
```

```
temp = {"a": {"b": {"c": 123}}}
print(temp)  # {'a': {'b': {'c': 123}}}
update_dict_dot(temp, "a.b.c", 456)
print(temp)  # {'a': {'b': {'c': 456}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @rdas mentioned here is the code to do that

```
temp = {"a": {"b": {"c":{"d": 123} } } }
flat = "a.b.c.d"
new_val = 456
split_val = flat.split('.')
trav_data = temp
for keys in split_val:
    trav_data = trav_data[keys]
print(trav_data)
```

output

```
123
```

Comment: That is a specific solution, that won't work with a different amount of keys

Comment: @azro I have edited to be more generic, if number of keys are unknown